# ExoPlayer sometimes fails with java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) when the file exists

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-download-manager

I'm using ExoPlayer from **androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.1** to play video from local storage (Download folder - files downloaded by using Android DownloadManager). UUID is just a string like this **"31a13faf-e1f4-4357-879f-e140aee63ab0"** that I get from the back-end.

Method in my ViewModel to trigger download for each file

```
private fun downloadVideos() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mediaRepository.getMediaItems().forEach { item ->
                downloader.downloadFile(item.uuid, item.filePath)
            }
        }
    }
```

and the Downloader class

```
class AndroidDownloader(
    context: Context
): Downloader {

    private val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DownloadManager::class.java)

    override fun downloadFile(title: String, url: String): Long {
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(url.toUri())
            .setMimeType("video/mp4")
            .setNotificationVisibility(
                DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED
                    or DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE
            )
            .setTitle(title)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title)
        return downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }
}
```

After success downloading, I play video, when I get events from the back-end.

```
override fun playVideo(uuid: String) {
        videoIsPlaying = true
        currentUri = fileParser.getUri(uuid)
        currentUri?.let {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                videoPlayer.playVideo(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

**fileParser** returns URI for the downloaded file if it can find any file with that **uuid** (in my case this method always returns URIs, they are not null)

```
class FileParser(private val context: Context, private val pref: DefaultSharedPref) {

    private val listOfUris = mutableListOf<Uri>()

    fun getUri(uuid: String) : Uri? {
        if (listOfUris.isEmpty()) {
            val manager: DownloadManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

            pref.getVideoIds().forEach {
                val uri = manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(it.toLong())
                uri.path?.let {
                    listOfUris.add(uri)
                }
            }
        }
        listOfUris.forEach {
            val fileName = context.getFileName(it)
            if (fileName == uuid)
                return it
        }
        return null
    }
}

fun Context.getFileName(uri: Uri): String? = when(uri.scheme) {
    ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT -> getContentFileName(uri)
    else -> uri.path?.let(::File)?.name
}

private fun Context.getContentFileName(uri: Uri): String? = runCatching {
    contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        return@use cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME).let(cursor::getString)
    }
}.getOrNull()
```

This is my playVideo method

```
fun playVideo(uri: Uri) {
        player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
        player.prepare()
        player.play()
    }
```

And now, what I'm facing with this - sometimes the video is playing well for a few hours, sometimes for a few minutes, but after some amount of time I'm getting this Exception.

```
Playback error androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:652)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:624)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.datasource.ContentDataSource$ContentDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at androidx.media3.datasource.ContentDataSource.open(ContentDataSource.java:157)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272)
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1006)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:780)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:2029)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1967)
at androidx.media3.datasource.ContentDataSource.open(ContentDataSource.java:89)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1006) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

The file still exists at this point and I didn't change the title of it. After first catch of this exception video won't play anymore. Only two ways to fix it - delete the app and install it again or clear the cash. It helps but only for short amount of time. After some point exception will return. Can somebody say what is going wrong? Uri is looking like that **content://downloads/all_downloads/1012**. I'm using JetpackCompose for my UI

```
AnimatedVisibility(visible = videoIsPlaying) {
            AndroidView(
                factory = { context ->
                    PlayerView(context).also {
                        it.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
                        it.useController = false
                        it.player = videoPlayer.player
                    }
                },
                update = {
                    when (lifecycle) {
                        Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                            it.onPause()
                            it.player?.pause()
                        }
                        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                            it.onResume()
                        }
                        else -> Unit
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .aspectRatio(16 / 9f)
            )
        }
```

Thank you!

I've tried to use DefaultDataSource but it didn't help

```
 private val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(app)
    private val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
        app,
        defaultDataSourceFactory
    )

    fun playVideo(uri: Uri) {
        val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
        player.setMediaSource(source)
        player.prepare()
        player.playWhenReady = false
        player.play()
    }
```

Also I've tried to add this `videoPlayer.player.seekTo(0)` to restart video, but still problem wasn't fixed.

I thought maybe this was because of permission (I didn't add them, as I understand we don't need them if files belong to your app) but even when I add them - nothing changes.

Comment: Please show us your error properly.

Comment: `fileParser returns URI for the downloaded file` Nobody knows how that uri is determined. Please post code in such a way that it is obvious you ask the download manager for an uri if indeed that is what you do.

Comment: Also it is unclear where you got a uuid from. (Dont tell us. Instead adapt your code to show).

Comment: Try downloading the video directly from your app, such as using OkHttp, rather than using `DownloadManager`.

Comment: @blackapps fixed, hope now it's clearer

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I will try, Is something wrong with DownloadManager?

Comment: `DownloadManager` delegates downloading to a system app. Given the way permissions work on newer versions of Android, I worry that you are losing read access to the downloaded content.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sounds like my case. Does that mean that DownloadManger is better to use in situations where you need only to download a file but not use it in the app?

Comment: Personally, I have not used `DownloadManager` seriously in a decade. That being said, yes, it seems more appropriate for "download and forget" sorts of scenarios, as opposed to using it content that you are aiming to use in your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare good then. Will use your variant, thank you

Comment: You can just continue to use DownloadManager. But you dont need to use its provider (by using the uri obtained from the manager). You can maybe better determine file path. It will be like /storage/emulated/0/<filename>. Use both File.exists() and File.canRead() before you start Exoplayer with the file. And to be serious: i used the manager today. Not a decade ago ;-).And a file is a file: it does not matter how it is downloaded. @CommonsWare.

Comment: @blackapps: I'm glad that it works for you. Personally, I would not rely upon it, as between device manufacturer modifications and general OS changes, I do not know that I can trust it, especially in light of continuing restrictions on who can access what in key directories, such as `Downloads/`.

Comment: @blackapps thank you for your response, it is also working like a charm. And as a short-term solution, it will be ideal for me. Maybe you know what a problem is with an uris from the manager? In the long term, I think it is better to use CommonsWare solutions to not use real paths in the app.

Comment: CommonsWare did say nothing about real paths.

Comment: @blackapps Yeah, I didn't express myself correctly. I mean that with this solution I can have some problems in the future. If the restrictions will be changed (as CommonsWare said). But it isn't my question now. Both variants fix my problem. Only one mystery, what the problem is with an uris that I get from DownloadManager, and why it's working well with the real path?